# List of methods in code matching a signature (C# VS using Roslyn or an extension)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

Suppose I am looking for all methods in my solution that match a given signature, is there a Roslyn based or otherwise way to find and list all the matching methods?

Comment: what kind of signature do you have?

Comment: @vasily.sib : for a specific example consider something that takes a bool and returns string.

Comment: oh, I see now that you searching a specific text in your sources. VS can search by regex, for your example this will be `string \S+\(bool \S+\)`

Comment: @vasily.sib :  thank you , but no text search based solution please :)

Comment: if you don't want a text based solution you'd need to compile the classes and then use reflection for the search

Comment: @SebastianL : so Roslyn can not be used for such scenarios?

Comment: Roslyn is doing exactly this, but it's only compiling "skeleton classes" to search, but i do not know how much modifications do you have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the [Syntax Analysis API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis) of Roslyn, if you only need the type names (as written in code) for the return type and parameter types. Once you get a [MethodDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.methoddeclarationsyntax?view=roslyn-dotnet) node you can use the Identifier, ReturnType and ParameterList properties to get the signature. Since you are only interested in methods and not other syntax nodes, use a syntax walker to visit only methods. The article of the first link has a section about them. Notice that C# and VB.NET have different APIs, although similar.

If you need fully resolved type names (with namespace, assembly, etc.), you need to use the [Semantic Analysis API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/semantic-analysis) (symbols, binding) with a Compilation that gives you the semantic model and you can query the symbol of a syntax node.

The links include docs and sample code.